# Pandas module not found

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a AWS EMR cluster and a Jupyert Note book on another instance connected through livy , I have installed packages on EMR master and node, Jupyter seems to recognize all packages except pandas.

I have checked sys.executable(/usr/bin/python3)which is same on Jypter and terminal .

An error was encountered:

```
Pandas >= 0.19.2 must be installed; however, it was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 2085, in toPandas
    require_minimum_pandas_version()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 129, in require_minimum_pandas_version
    "it was not found." % minimum_pandas_version)
ImportError: Pandas >= 0.19.2 must be installed; however, it was not found.
```

Can some one please help me?

Comment: Have you tried installing pandas? pip install pandas

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: pandas==1.1.1 from file:///home/hadoop/packages/pandas-1.1.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl in /root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages . this shows me it has already been installed

Answer (score 0):

It is complaining that it cannot find a `pandas` of at least the minimum required version, which is equal to `0.19.2` or greater. Have you checked in your dependencies whether maybe you have installed an earlier version?

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: pandas==1.1.1 from file:///home/hadoop/packages/pandas-1.1.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl in /root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages . this shows me it has already  been installed .

Comment: Clearly the Python interpreter does not have access to this path. Check for `>>> import sys; sys.path` in the environment where the python interpreter lives. The path pointing to the location of the package files should appear listed there. If it doesn't, it is normal that it does not work.

Comment: I have appended the path to sys.path but still same error persists

Comment: Try `sys.path.insert(0, path)` instead of appending

Comment: Hi mosegui, I tried the sys.path.insert(0, path) . it did not work same error persists.